# $PATH editting does not work

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, environment-variables, path

I am using Ubuntu 64-bit on a VM and installed an app, added it to $PATH using export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH in my terminal (T1). Worked fine. Then i wanted to use the command in another terminal (T2) and got an error message that the command is unknown. I checked echo $PATH and the path was really missing, while I did the same in the other terminal (and it's child terminals) where it was in there. Then i added the the path again, in T2, opened a new terminal (T3) where the path was missing again.
To resolve it, I navigated to $HOME/.profile and manually added the path, but it doesn't change anything, same as above.
Anyone can help me with this? Thanks

EDIT: Exact line added to .profile: `. "$HOME/solana-release/bin"` (I used the scheme from the line above). I used `source $HOME/.profile` in the new terminal. The response is `bash: .: /home/longroad/solana-release/bin: is a directory`

Comment: Using `$PWD` in setting the PATH is going to be dependent on your current working directory at the time you give the command. You would be better off setting the path either as an absolute or relative to `$HOME`.

Comment: @doneal24 I did both. Same problem anyways

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) for some examples of why exact error messages matter.

Comment: Literally that is my terminal in and output
```longroad@ubuntu:~$ solana --version
solana: command not found
```

Comment: What is the exact line you added to `$HOME/.profile`? Notice the dot in the file name that is missing in your post. Did you source `.profile` in your new terminal window? Please edit your post instead of answering in comments. Comments are transient.

Comment: fine @doneal24, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, when you apply a setting like that, it is applied across the entire system.

In Linux/Unix system, it is hierarchical and it only flows downwards.

Therefore, when you are in one shell and you export a new PATH, it does not apply to your other shells.

Your edit to .profile is wrong.

It should be `export PATH=$HOME/solana-release/bin:${PATH}`

Once that is done, then you can either source it within each shell, or log out and back in.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is exactly the same as before. :(

Comment: Did you remove your previous edit?